# Appending param to api request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

I have a method that is called, passed a file name, and then makes an API call to the back end to get a preauthorized link. I am attempting to append the parameter (filename) to the end of the URL, but it is causing my API request to 404.

How can I correctly pass a parameter with my API request and get back the preauthorized URL in the response?

**My file names may also contain spaces, which I suspect may have something to do with the request returning a 404.**

This is the call on my **front end**:

```
getPreauthorizedLink(fileName) {   
    console.log(fileName);
    var fileName = fileName;
    var url = 'reportPresignedURL/' + fileName;
    fetch(config.api.urlFor(url))
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((url) => {
        console.log(url);
    });
}
```

And this is the implementation of that API on the **back end**:

```
reports.get('/reportPresignedURL/:fileName', async (req, res) => {
    const subscriberID = req.query.subscriberID || 0;

    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

    var s3 = new AWS.S3();

    var params = { 
        Bucket: config.reportBucket,
        Key: req.params.fileName,
        Expires: 60 * 5
    }

    try {
        s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, function (err, url) {
            if(err)throw err;
            console.log(url)
            res.json(url);
        });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err.toString());
    }
});
```

I have tried isolating the issue down to just how I am passing the param by doing the following on the **front end**:

```
  getPreauthorizedLink(fileName){

    console.log(fileName);

    var fileName = fileName;

    var testFileName = 'test';

    var url = 'reportPresignedURL/' + testFileName.replace(/ /g, '%20').replace(/\//g, '%2F');

    fetch(config.api.urlFor(url))
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((url) => {

      console.log(url);
  });
  }
```

This is how I specify the API route in config.js:

```
reportPresignedURL: '/reports/reportPresignedURL',
```

I have also tried specifying it like this:

```
reportPresignedURL: '/reports/reportPresignedURL/:fileName',
```

For Your Information I have added this API route to my **config.js** in the front end.

Comment: You might want to recheck the url that you are requesting to. Looks like you are missing a `/` in the function `getPreauthorizedLink` at line `var url=...`

Comment: good point, updated that and it still 404s. I don't think I am correctly appending the parameter but not sure how to do that. The file name can contain spaces btw.

Comment: Are you sure that the url is `/reportPresignedURL/somefile`? In your server side code, you have written `reports.get(...`, so I am assuming you made an express router object and mounted this on some `/reports`

Comment: I am sure that is the correct URL as I have tested it before adding the capability to add parameters and it is able to hit it.

Comment: Ok so if filename contains spaces, do this instead `var url = 'reportPresignedURL/' + filename.replace(/ /g, '%20')`

Comment: trying this says filename is not defined.

Comment: Your variable name is fileName not filename. I wrote that comment quickly so I messed it up.. will update it

Comment: Good call! Even with that change it still 404s though :/

Comment: Well, then probably something wrong on your server. Try to `console.log` requests that come to the server, you can use morgan which is an npm package for this. Im pretty sure once you check the requests, you will see the problem. also if the requests result in 404 probably the file by that name doesn't exist

Comment: My file names can also contain forward slahes, which I think is also causing a problem with the route. How would I handle those?

Comment: Ok so finally, this should work `var url = 'reportPresignedURL/ + fileName.replace(/ /g, '%20').replace(/\//g, '%2F');`

Comment: Still getting a 404. I updated my post with what I have now test to isolate the issue down to just how I am passing the param.

Comment: 404 status code means that the file doesnt exist. Try requesting for a file that exists

Comment: It does not even hit my method on the back end, i.e. it is not hitting the API.

Comment: added  how I specify the route in my config.js

Comment: Is your back end serving the front end code? Are you requesting for the file from the same origin?

Comment: The back end makes a call to AWS S3 to get a preauthorized link for the file and returns that link to the front end. However the back end is not being called and just shows a 404 when it gets the request from the front end.

Comment: Is the request coming from same origin? It could be an issue with cors

Comment: I think the issue is with adding the filename to the end of the URL. When I make all the other calls that are prefixed by /reports/ they work. When I make this one, it doesn't even get the /reports/ prefix that I have in my config.js

Comment: The request does reach the back end, because it doesnt get timed out. Rather it returns 404 which means file not found. Try requesting for a file that exists

Comment: Fixed it. Adding my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by doing this:

```
getPreauthorizedLink(fileName){

    console.log(fileName);

    var fileName = fileName;

    let url = config.api.urlFor('reportPresignedURL', fileName);

    fetch(config.api.urlFor(url))
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((url) => {

            console.log(url);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use es6 syntax
   let url = `reportPresignedURL/${fileName}`;
 for Query params

let url = `reportPresignedURL/?fileName=${fileName}`;

Comment: Trying this results in an error: ' ;  expected after the first curly brace'